# my question is always put on hold as off-topic or duplicate or closed why?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic, duplicate-answers, on-hold

I posted many questions but most of the questions are put on hold as off-topic or duplicate or closed i dont know reason may be my english how to explain my issues or otherwise some senior stackusers dominate me?

1. [How to handle a senior staff always fight with all staff in a government office?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103122) [on hold]
2. [in my pc google search is not working why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47249777)
3. [Is there any free android app for app for send sms to store in a website?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/186885) [on hold]
4. [creation of "Hello World" in Multiple indian Languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146721/creation-of-hello-world-in-multiple-indian-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1) [duplicate]

Comment: You keep asking blatantly off-topic questions on Stack Overflow. Of course they're getting closed... Maybe read up more on the scope of the sites before posting? Questions about your computer do not belong on Stack Overflow, for example.

Comment: Well... I guess your count of duplicates has gone up again..

Comment: duplicate has a duplicate? What is a “closed”, “on hold”, or “duplicate” question? is different from my question, please understand clearly

Comment: We understand everything clearly. Did you consider that you are the one who have missed the plenty of guidance available?

Comment: "Web designer cum promoter" just sounds... off. You may want to consider changing that name. I didn't even know you could have multiple different names across the network.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general - the close reasons and comments actually cover what you need to know. In general questions need to have a reasonable possible solution (even on heavily subjective sites), and provide enough information for someone to actually post a reasonable answer.

Every site actually has specific pages on the [help] pages which would help you understand the things missing in your questions.

Consider scope first - is this on topic (and this is literally step 0. Anyone who asks questions about macarame on SU will have me only amused for half a second) , and is it possible to answer this at all?

Consider what sufficient detail is. While I consider ESR's "asking questions the smart way" in its entirety to be heavy reading - have a look at [this second on good and bad questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#examples) and compare them to yours.

Consider whether your question is *sufficiently distinctive* from other questions. If similar questions have been asked before, you may want to *reference* these, and mention why your question is different, and what answers from the other question you've tried and haven't worked

---

As for your questions - well... in many cases, they are not very good. I don't use workplace.se so I'll not address the first question.

The second one is a textbook case of how not to approach problem solving. Well, that and its off topic for SO. As I sometimes feel I need to remind people, there's sites outside SO - and reading the help and tour is good too.

One does not *simply* go "its broken"  on a random site. You should consider once you're on the appropriate site- People need to know what's your OS, and your browser, and hopefully what you've done to try to fix it. On SU, we get asked the sort of question you've asked so often, with varying levels of detail that we have a [canonical question](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) covering what people ask about malware, and questions get closed against it as a dupe.

As for the third - on *most* sites, product recommendations are off topic. The close reason says what it is. There's even an [old blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) covering it - though software recommendations being OT came as a natural extension of it. While the software recommendations site exists, you may want to dig into the quality standards there before posting - your question in its current form would be closed.

["creation of “Hello World” in Multiple indian Languages"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/146721/creation-of-hello-world-in-multiple-indian-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1) seems a 'lazy' subset of another question and was closed as a duplicate. In short, it wasn't distinct enough.

Answer (score 1):

These questions seem to come from four different sites in the Stack Exchange network, and to have been closed for different reasons.

You seem to have ample reputation to participate in the Meta site of each of those sites.

As [commented by @Animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303680/my-question-is-always-put-on-hold-as-off-topic-or-duplicate-or-closed-why#comment987308_303680) I think you should:

> read up more on the scope of the sites before posting

and if that does not lead you to a better understanding of why a particular question is unsuitable for a particular site, then ask about what is missing from your understanding on the Meta for that particular site.